# matplotlib pick_event returns incorrect pressed keys

Tags: matplotlib, plot, wxpython, mouseevent

I am writing a program that incorporates a matplotlib plot into a wxPython GUI.  I would like to be able to differentiate between simple click, OPTION-click, COMMAND-click etc. on some of the plot elements (in order to do different things depending on which key was pressed while clicking on the plot element).

My code for this is as follows:

- binding the matplotlib "pick_event" to the handler:

  ```
  self.figure.canvas.mpl_connect('pick_event', self.onClick)
  ```
- in the handler, checking which/if any key was pressed

  ```
  def onClick(self, event):
      """handle clicking on different objects in the plotarea"""
      ## get relevant event data
      ## ... other stuff here ...
      pressedKey = None
      pressedKey = event.mouseevent.key    ## key pressed while clicking
      print "You pressed key '%s' while clicking!" % pressedKey
      ## ... more stuff here ...
      if pressedKey == "alt+alt":
          self.onOptionClick(...)
  ```
- ...and then go on to other functions

My problem, however, is that what is returned by matplotlib as the pressed key is simply - wrong.

For example, when I open my program, plot my data, click on points (without any keys pressed), I keep getting "You pressed key 'ctrl+control' while clicking!".  If I option-click on a data point, this then changes to a permanent "You pressed key 'alt+alt' while clicking!", regardless of whether I was pressing the option key or not.  Only once I have command-clicked on a data point does it return the correct "You pressed key 'None' while clicking!" for simple clicks.

(Not to mention that the pressedKey returns are pretty unintuitive:  Why "alt+alt" if I was simply pressing one "Alt/Option" key?  Why "ctrl+control' for command?)

It is very important for the correct functioning of my program to be able to differentiate between different types of clicks.

---

UPDATE #1:

Oh dear.  This is getting more and more confusing.  My sample code below is doing fine, my main program still isn't.  How could that be possible?  Also, my little example below did alternate between "None" responses and "" responses for simple clicks.  (I can't reproduce it; currently it's only giving me "None" responses - i.e. "You pressed key 'None' while clicking!")

Here's the example code:

```
#!/bin/usr/env python

import wx
import matplotlib as mpl
mpl.use('WXAgg')
from matplotlib.figure import Figure as mplFigure
from matplotlib.backends.backend_wxagg import FigureCanvasWxAgg as mplCanvas

class PlotPanel(wx.Panel):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent)

        self.figure = mplFigure(figsize=(9, 6))
        self.ax = self.figure.add_subplot(111)
        self.ax.plot([1, 2, 3, 4], [2, 3, 5, 8], marker="o", markersize=20, picker=10, linestyle="None")
        self.canvas = mplCanvas(self, -1, self.figure)

        self.figure.canvas.mpl_connect('pick_event', self.onClick)

    def onClick(self, event):
        pressedKey = None
        pressedKey = event.mouseevent.key                           ## key pressed while clicking
        print "You pressed key '%s' while clicking!" % pressedKey

class MainFrame(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, -1, "matplotlib pick_event problem")
        self.plotarea = PlotPanel(self)
        self.mainSizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        self.mainSizer.Add(self.plotarea, 1, wx.EXPAND)
        self.SetSizer(self.mainSizer)
        self.mainSizer.Fit(self)

if __name__ == "__main__":

    app = wx.App(False)
    mainFrame = MainFrame()
    mainFrame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

---

UPDATE #2:

OK, so the problem seems to be that my handlers sometimes open up other windows, and that the key release event gets "lost" in those windows.  That is, matplotlib never gets to know that the key in question was released, and so on the next click, it is still under the impression that the key is pressed, even when it is not.  If you change the handler above to

```
    def onClick(self, event):
        pressedKey = None
        pressedKey = event.mouseevent.key                           ## key pressed while clicking
        wx.MessageBox("You pressed key '%s' while clicking!" % pressedKey)
```

it actually reproduces the problem.

So I guess my question now becomes:  How do I (manually) tell matplotlib that the key was released?  "event.Skip()" is not working; python is telling me

```
"PickEvent instance has no attribute 'Skip'"
```

Comment: what version of mpl, what OS, and what backend?

Comment: @tcaswell:  Matplotlib version 1.3.x, Mac OS X 10.8.4, WXAgg backend

Comment: my un-research instinct is that this is a bug and should be reported as an issue on github

Comment: can you post a full runnable chunk of code that reproduces this?

Comment: @tcaswell:  Thanks for your comments!  I really appreciate somebody trying to help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest solution here is to forgo `mouseevent.key` and use `wx.GetKeyState` function:

```
def onClick(self, event):
    print event
    keys = ""
    if wx.GetKeyState(wx.WXK_CONTROL):
        keys += "ctrl "
    if wx.GetKeyState(wx.WXK_ALT):
        keys += "alt "
    wx.MessageBox("You pressed key '%s' while clicking!" % keys)
```

If this won't work for you, it's probably best to track the up and down key presses on your own.  **BUT**, to do that, you need to do it in **EVERY** window that can get the focus while you're doing the tracking, which is a significant pain.

Here's an example:

```
class PlotPanel(wx.Panel):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent)

        self.figure = mplFigure(figsize=(9, 6))
        self.ax = self.figure.add_subplot(111)
        self.ax.plot([1, 2, 3, 4], [2, 3, 5, 8], marker="o", markersize=20, picker=10, linestyle="None")
        self.canvas = mplCanvas(self, -1, self.figure)

        self.figure.canvas.mpl_connect('pick_event', self.onClick)
        self.canvas.Bind(wx.EVT_KEY_DOWN, self._on_key_down)
        self.canvas.Bind(wx.EVT_KEY_UP, self._on_key_up)

        self.states = {"cmd":False, "ctrl":False, "shift":False}

    def onClick(self, event):
        print event
        #print "You pressed key '%s' while clicking!" % pressedKey
        print "Pressed keys:", [k for k in self.states if self.states[k]]
        dlg = TestDialog(self)
        dlg.ShowModal()

    def _on_key_down(self, evt):
        self._set_state(evt)
        evt.Skip()

    def _on_key_up(self, evt):
        self._set_state(evt)
        evt.Skip()

    def _set_state(self, evt):
        self.states["cmd"] = evt.CmdDown()
        self.states["ctrl"] = evt.ControlDown()
        self.states["shift"] = evt.ShiftDown()

class MainFrame(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, -1, "matplotlib pick_event problem")
        self.plotarea = PlotPanel(self)
        self.mainSizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        self.mainSizer.Add(self.plotarea, 1, wx.EXPAND)
        self.SetSizer(self.mainSizer)
        self.mainSizer.Fit(self)

class TestDialog(wx.Dialog):

    def __init__(self, parent):     

        pre = wx.PreDialog()
        pre.SetExtraStyle(wx.DIALOG_EX_CONTEXTHELP)
        pre.Create(parent, -1, "sample dialog", size=(200, 100), style=wx.CAPTION|wx.RESIZE_BORDER)
        self.PostCreate(pre)

        self.parent = parent
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_KEY_DOWN, self.parent._on_key_down)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_KEY_UP, self.parent._on_key_up)

        btn = wx.Button(self, -1, "OK")
        btn.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self._OnClick)

    def _OnClick(self, evt):
        self.EndModal(wx.ID_OK)
```

In general, I find the matplotlib's wx canvas to be very useful, but it's also not a complete solution for all corner cases.

Comment: This is a very late THANK YOU for the perfect solution to this problem.  The wx.GetKeyState() did the trick; it works like a charm now!  Thank you so much!!!

Answer (score 0):

So the problem was that my key release event was being eaten up somewhere - and since my program consists of many panels, widgets, dialogs, I never managed to find out where exactly.  But I added a manually created "key up" event at the end of my "onClick" handler and sent it to the plot panel, which worked out fine!

Here's a (partial) solution to my example code:

```
def onClick(self, event):
    pressedKey = None
    pressedKey = event.mouseevent.key                           ## key pressed while clicking
    wx.MessageBox("You pressed key '%s' while clicking!" % pressedKey)
    ## manually send a "key up" event to the figure canvas
    ## since the other one gets eaten up somewhere...
    ## (comment out the two lines below to see the problem)
    manual_key_up_event = wx.KeyEvent(wx.EVT_KEY_UP.typeId)
    wx.PostEvent(self.figure.canvas, manual_key_up_event)
```

Comment: Good you figured this out.  I will leave the bounty open for the week in the hope that a WX expert can provide a more general explanation than manually setting the key state.

Comment: OK, not an ideal solution, obviously, since now somebody who e.g. keeps the command key pressed while clicking on the plot repeatedly will have their second click processed as if the command key was no longer pressed.  But better this behavior than the other way around, I guess...

Comment: @tcaswell:  Thanks!  I just realized that this is more like a workaround than an actual solution to the problem.  For the reasons stated above, it would still be preferable to find the missing key release event, rather than manually adding one.